# Alertas de error en angular

Tags: angular

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de angular, pero no se si es por alguna versión ya sea de angular CLI, o de nodejs que me sale este error, (o alerta).

el proyecto como tal funciona, pero no quisiera seguir viendo estas alertas

la mayoria de alertas me aparecen en los arvhivos `.ts`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podes mostrar el codigo que usas parece no estar bien definido
forRoot(routes: Route[], config?: ExtraOptions): ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule>
https://runebook.dev/es/docs/angular/api/router/extraoptions

Comment: Tengo en la mayoria de Routing ese mismo error, que parte del codigo te muestro?, o te subo como tal todo el codigo que tengo dentro de un Routing.ts?

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude solucionar, y lo que pasaba era que estaba abriendo en la misma ventana de Visual Studio Code, la parte del backend y frontend, ya abrí solo el proyecto de front y se me desaparecieron los errores

Comment: Si igualmente interesante porque vi  que en el  caso de que el backend no admita una tecnología push se puede utilizar la propiedad onSameUrlNavigation para  para obtener los datos mas recientes Lo cual no había aplicado nunca https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti, que tengas un excelente día

Comment: Tuve un problema parecido, termino siendo mi Instalación de **Visual Studio Code** ya que al actualizarse hubo un error, lo solucione reinstalando Visual Studio Code.